# JaxB Unmarshall error : java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"code"). Expected elements are <{}section>

Tags: java, jaxb

please advise what may be the issue with this JAXB Unmarshall code
This is the error message I receive when I try to unmarshall the XML I have provided below:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"code"). Expected elements are <{}section>**

Borrower class is parsed using JaxB based on the XSD , using JDK 1.7 and Eclipse IDE.

:

```
public class UnmarshallApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    try {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(Borrower.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
                public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage(),event.getLinkedException());
                                                                   }
        });


    StringReader xmlCCR = new StringReader(returnValue2());
    JAXBElement<Borrower> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xmlCCR), Borrower.class);
    Borrower productListResponse = root.getValue();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Borrower class :

```
package bg.rbb.unmarshall;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"section"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "borrower")

public class Borrower {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Section> section;
@XmlAttribute(name = "code", required = true)
protected String code;
@XmlAttribute(name = "name")
protected String name;

public List<Section> getSection() {
    if (section == null) {
        section = new ArrayList<Section>();
    }
    return this.section;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String value) {
    this.code = value;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}
```

}

XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:wmh="http://www.wmhelp.com/2003/eGenerator" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="borr-info-list">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="borrower" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="req-file-name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="req-file-time" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="req-file-user" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="req-file-entity" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="out-file-time" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="borr_count" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="borrower">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="section" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="section">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="active-credits"/>
    <xs:element ref="overdue-history"/>
    <xs:element ref="new-credits"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="entity-type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="active-credits">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="summaries" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="cred-count" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="source-entity-count" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="summaries">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="summary" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="grouping-attribute" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="summary">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="date-from" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="amount-approved" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="amount-drawn" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="monthly-installment" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="outstanding-performing-principal" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="outstanding-overdue-principal" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="balance-sheet-value" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="off-balance-sheet-value" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="overdue-payment-period" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="rest" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="term" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="active" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="year" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="category" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="months-count" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="max-cred-count" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="max-outstanding-overdue-principal" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="max-outstanding-overdue-interest-and-others" 
  type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="max-off-balance-sheet-dues" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="date-last-correction" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="overdue-history">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="summary" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="new-credits">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="summary" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<borrower>
   <code>7777777777</code>
   <name>FirstName Surname LastName</name>
   <section>
      <entity-type>banks</entity-type>
      <active-credits>
         <cred-count>2</cred-count>
         <source-entity-count>1</source-entity-count>
         <summaries>
            <grouping-attribute>type</grouping-attribute>
            <summary>
               <date-from>2017-12-31</date-from>
               <type>Card</type>
               <amount-approved>4000</amount-approved>
               <amount-drawn>2105</amount-drawn>
               <monthly-installment>0</monthly-installment>
               <outstanding-performing-principal>2105</outstanding-performing-principal>
               <outstanding-overdue-principal>0</outstanding-overdue-principal>
               <balance-sheet-value>2105</balance-sheet-value>
               <off-balance-sheet-value>1895</off-balance-sheet-value>
            </summary>
            <summary>
               <date-from>2017-12-31</date-from>
               <type>Овърдрафт</type>
               <amount-approved>7434</amount-approved>
               <amount-drawn>7447</amount-drawn>
               <monthly-installment>0</monthly-installment>
               <outstanding-performing-principal>7434</outstanding-performing-principal>
               <outstanding-overdue-principal>13</outstanding-overdue-principal>
               <balance-sheet-value>7484</balance-sheet-value>
               <off-balance-sheet-value>0</off-balance-sheet-value>
            </summary>
         </summaries>
         <summaries>
            <grouping-attribute>overdue-payment-period</grouping-attribute>
            <summary>
               <date-from>2017-12-31</date-from>
               <overdue-payment-period>от 0 до 30 дни</overdue-payment-period>
               <amount-approved>11434</amount-approved>
               <amount-drawn>9552</amount-drawn>
               <monthly-installment>0</monthly-installment>
               <outstanding-performing-principal>9539</outstanding-performing-principal>
               <outstanding-overdue-principal>13</outstanding-overdue-principal>
               <balance-sheet-value>9589</balance-sheet-value>
               <off-balance-sheet-value>1895</off-balance-sheet-value>
            </summary>
         </summaries>
         <summaries>
            <grouping-attribute>rest</grouping-attribute>
            <summary>
               <date-from>2017-12-31</date-from>
               <rest>До една година</rest>
               <amount-approved>7434</amount-approved>
               <amount-drawn>7447</amount-drawn>
               <monthly-installment>0</monthly-installment>
               <outstanding-performing-principal>7434</outstanding-performing-principal>
               <outstanding-overdue-principal>13</outstanding-overdue-principal>
               <balance-sheet-value>7484</balance-sheet-value>
               <off-balance-sheet-value>0</off-balance-sheet-value>
            </summary>
            <summary>
               <date-from>2017-12-31</date-from>
               <rest>Над една година</rest>
               <amount-approved>4000</amount-approved>
               <amount-drawn>2105</amount-drawn>
               <monthly-installment>0</monthly-installment>
               <outstanding-performing-principal>2105</outstanding-performing-principal>
               <outstanding-overdue-principal>0</outstanding-overdue-principal>
               <balance-sheet-value>2105</balance-sheet-value>
               <off-balance-sheet-value>1895</off-balance-sheet-value>
            </summary>
         </summaries>
         <summaries>
            <grouping-attribute>term</grouping-attribute>
            <summary>
               <date-from>2017-12-31</date-from>
               <term>Над една година</term>
               <amount-approved>11434</amount-approved>
               <amount-drawn>9552</amount-drawn>
               <monthly-installment>0</monthly-installment>
               <outstanding-performing-principal>9539</outstanding-performing-principal>
               <outstanding-overdue-principal>13</outstanding-overdue-principal>
               <balance-sheet-value>9589</balance-sheet-value>
               <off-balance-sheet-value>1895</off-balance-sheet-value>
            </summary>
         </summaries>
      </active-credits>
      <overdue-history />
      <new-credits />
   </section>
</borrower>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the xsd (and thus the generated POJOs) and the xml do not match.

For example, as you can see in the Borrower class, name and code are annotated with `@XmlAttribute` but your xml does not have them as attributes but as elements instead.

To be more specific your xml looks like this:

```
<borrower>
   <code>7777777777</code>
   <name>FirstName Surname LastName</name>
   <section>
    ...
</borrower>
```

But the POJO is built to expect something like this (focusing only on code and name):

```
<borrower code="someCode" name="someName">
   <section>
    ...
</borrower>
```

and continuing on there are more similar issues. So we have to fix your xsd. Is it under your control?

If you change your xsd to the one below, you will be able to unmarshal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:wmh="http://www.wmhelp.com/2003/eGenerator"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="borr-info-list">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="borrower" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="req-file-name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="req-file-time" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="req-file-user" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="req-file-entity" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="out-file-time" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="borr_count" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="borrower">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="section" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="section">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="active-credits"/>
                <xs:element ref="overdue-history"/>
                <xs:element ref="new-credits"/>
                <xs:element name="entity-type" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="active-credits">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="summaries" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="cred-count" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="source-entity-count" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="summaries">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="summary" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="grouping-attribute" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="summary">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="date-from" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="amount-approved" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="amount-drawn" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="monthly-installment" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="outstanding-performing-principal" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="outstanding-overdue-principal" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="balance-sheet-value" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="off-balance-sheet-value" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="overdue-payment-period" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="rest" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="term" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="active" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="year" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="category" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="months-count" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="max-cred-count" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="max-outstanding-overdue-principal" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="max-outstanding-overdue-interest-and-others"
                            type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="max-off-balance-sheet-dues" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="date-last-correction" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="overdue-history">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="summary" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="new-credits">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="summary" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mart for your fast response, works like a charm :)